# Infinite for Loop while iterating over an object

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop

I am attempting to store data from an object with arrays into another object with arrays. The data has been stored in the object from a CSV. In this situation the data will start at index 8 and then 19 and 30 and so on and so on. I increment I by 11 to account for this. Not sure why I'm hitting this infinite loop but it's got me quite stuck.

```
for (var key in states){
            var tempDefault = 0;
            var tempTotalLoans = 0;
            if (states.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                //Get Total Defaults and Loans
                for (var i = defaultIndex; i < states[key].length; i + 11) {

                    if (states[key][i] != null && states[key][i] != '') {
                        tempDefault = parseInt(states[key][i]);
                    };
                };

                var defaults =  tempDefault;
                var totalLoans = tempTotalLoans;
                var percent = (defaults/totalLoans)*100;

                defaultsObject[key].push(Math.round(percent));
                defaultsObject[key].push(totalLoans);
                defaultsObject[key].push(defaults);

                loadMap();
            }
        }
```

Comment: You never increase `i` in the inner loop

Comment: Your `i + 11` just creates a new value that isn't assigned to anything. You're looking for `i += 11`.

Comment: Wow I need more coffee...of course += thanks krillgar

Answer (score 0):

Your i + 11 just creates a new value that isn't assigned to anything. You're looking for i += 11. – krillgar